# Cannot remove Windows directory path containing backslashes using Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, substitution, backslash

I want to remove the first part of a file's full path using a regex in perl.  But it doesn't work when backslashes are used in the paths.  Consider test.pl below

```
$fileName = 'C:\someDirectory\anotherDirectory\someFile.txt';
$dirName  = 'C:\someDirectory';

print "$fileName\n";

$fileName =~ s/$dirName//;

print "$fileName\n";


$fileName = 'C:#someDirectory#anotherDirectory#someFile.txt';
$dirName  = 'C:#someDirectory';

print "$fileName\n";

$fileName =~ s/$dirName//;

print "$fileName\n";
```

Output looks like this:

```
C:\someDirectory\anotherDirectory\someFile.txt
C:\someDirectory\anotherDirectory\someFile.txt
C:#someDirectory#anotherDirectory#someFile.txt
#anotherDirectory#someFile.txt
```

Why doesn't the substitution work when backslashes are in the string?  How can I get around this?

Comment: In a regex pattern, `\s` means "match a whitespace character". `\a` means "match character `07`".

Answer (score 1):

#### Literal Strings in a Regex

A backslash is a regex special character, therefore it must be escaped if it's intended as part of a literal string within the regex.

To do that, you can simply use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or the `\Q...\E` escape sequence:

```
my $fileName = 'C:\someDirectory\anotherDirectory\someFile.txt';
my $dirName  = 'C:\someDirectory';

print "$fileName\n";

$fileName =~ s/\Q$dirName\E//;

print "$fileName\n";
```

Outputs:

```
C:\someDirectory\anotherDirectory\someFile.txt
\anotherDirectory\someFile.txt
```

#### Path::Class for File & Dir Manipulation

Alternatively, you can use a module like [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) for cross platform compatible file and directory manipulation.

The following is your same goal executed thusly:

```
use Path::Class;

my $file = file('C:\someDirectory\anotherDirectory\someFile.txt');
my $dir  = dir('C:\someDirectory');

my $rel = $file->relative($dir);

print "$rel\n";
```

Outputs:

```
anotherDirectory\someFile.txt
```

Comment: Path::Class seems like the right way to go but the quotemeta is very instructive too.  Much appreciated!